# Modify selected directory access permission in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, file-permissions, acl, pascalscript, network-service

In my project, I have an `TInputDirWizardPage` where user can select a directory for a database backup. So it can be any drive. I need to add `NETWORK SERVICE` account to the user list of this directory and modify it.

[image]

Is it possible to set this in `[Dir]` section? If not how can I implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the `[Dirs]` section can set permissions for the "networkservice". Use [`Permissions` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=dirssection&anchor=Permissions) with [`networkservice`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=usergroupids)-prefixed value:

```
[Dirs]
Name: {code:GetDir}; Permissions: networkservice-readexec
```

```pascal
[Code]
var 
  InputDirPage: TInputDirWizardPage;

function GetDir(Param: string): string;
begin
  Result := InputDirPage.Values[0];
end;
```